# Looking for a linux terminal (not drop-down) that can rename tabs and save them including their paths

Tags: linux, terminal

As the title says, I'm looking for a linux terminal (not drop-down) that can rename tabs and save them including their paths.

I have tried terminator, I can rename the tabs but I can't save correctly the layout and state such as paths.
Guake is almost perfect, I can do all what I need but I also need the terminal to be in a window, not drop-down

I found similar questions but none of the answers work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might ask on Software Recommendations, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: no, I didn't know about that site. I could try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found ROXTerm, which does what I needed.